# How to catch ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following Rspec:

```
before { model.update(calendar_id: nil) }
...
expect { job.perform_now(item_id) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation)
```

which fails with the following error message:

> ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
> Mysql2::Error: Column 'calendar_id' cannot be null

What happens is that the job updates the `model` (`model` doesn't have non-null constraint) and sets `calendar_id` to `NULL`, but it also invokes a callback which has the following code:

```
another_model.update_all(calendar_id: calendar_id)
```

On `another_model` there is a non-null constraint set. So, as `calendar_is` is `NULL`, the `update_all` statement fails, which is fine. But why doesn't Rspec catch the error?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you have a not null constraint the database will prevent you from inserting/updating with null values. That's kind of the whole point. You also can't add the constraint if your table contains nulls. What possible real life scenario is this test covering?

Comment: By supressing the error you're just hiding the fact that the database record was not actually updated. Call `model.reload` for a rude awakening.

Comment: @max thanks. Use: when migrating a feature from one table to another, but still maintaining certain backward compatibility. Calendar is being moved from model A to model B, but changes to A need to be propagated to B for the time being. Nor A or B have null constraint atm, but will be introduced on B, while calendar will be dropped from A. Also, all calendars in B are populated and callbacks ensure that A never propagates null calendar to B.

Comment: That still doesn't really change my opinion that this should not be done and that there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the error is raised inside `before`, rather than in the `expect` block. So moving the logic from `before` inside `expect` resolves the issue, i.e.

```
expect do
  model.update(calendar_id: nil)
  job.perform_now(item_id) // not even needed
end.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation)
```